# Basic jq usage. How to get nested value

Tags: json, key, jq

This must be incredibly simple but the man page makes no sense to me.
`curl example.com/json` gives me

```
{
 "stats": {
  "storage_server.disk_total": XXXXXXXXXX
 },
 "counters": {}
}
```

and I want to extract the value `XXXXXXXXXX` of the disk_total. What is the syntax to do this?

Comment: `.stats[].storage_server` ? Works for me with an identical (I think) type of structure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. For learning how to construct jq queries, it is more useful to look at the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) than the "man" page. There's also a [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ).
2. The inner key name has a period in it, and therefore the `.keyname` shorthand cannot be used for it.  So you could write:

```
   .stats["storage_server.disk_total"]
```

or if your jq allows it:

```
   .stats."storage_server.disk_total"
```

These are both abbreviations for:

```
   .stats | .["storage_server.disk_total"]
```

Comment: This makes the most sense for someone using JSON/Python. 
`curl <cmd> |  jq '.value["ref"]["service"]'`

Answer (score 31):

To get *deeply* nested values by their key:

```
$ jq '.. |."storage_server.disk_total"? | select(. != null)'
```

[`..` is a shortcut for the zero-argument `recurse`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) -- an analog of  the XPath `//` operator.

Answer (score 8):

Tho dot in `storage_server.disk_total" needs to be escaped to prevent it from being interpreted as an object key separator. so you can use:

```
jq '.stats."storage_server.disk_total"'
```

assuming that `XXXXXXXXXX` is a valid JSON number in your real JSON.